# C++ combine class objects obtained from istream

Tags: c++, class

I am very new to C++. This is literally the first class I am writing (some code is taken from *C++Primer*). I have a logical error while trying to combine class objects with the same name. Here is the thing:

- my class holds student record: name, number of passed courses and
  total sum of marks (to calculate mark average)
- constructor gets data from `istream`

  ```
  struct StudentEntry {
      StudentEntry() = default;
      StudentEntry(std::istream &);

      std::string getStudentName() const { return name; }
      StudentEntry& combine (const StudentEntry&);
      double avgMark() const;

      std::string name = "";
      unsigned passCources = 0;
      double markSum = 0.0;
  };
  ```
- `combine` function is meant to += data members (`passCources` & `markSum`):

  ```
  StudentEntry& StudentEntry::combine(const StudentEntry& st) {
      passCources += st.passCources;
      markSum += st.markSum;
      return *this;
  }
  ```
- `avgMark` is calculating mark average:

  ```
  double StudentEntry::avgMark() const {
      return passCources ? markSum / passCources : 0;
  }
  ```
- when I am combining more than 2 objects in `main`, I am getting wrong
  mark sum and average

  ```
  int main() {
      StudentEntry st;
      if (read(std::cin, st)) {
          StudentEntry nextSt;
          while (read(std::cin, nextSt)) {
              if (st.getStudentName() == nextSt.getStudentName())
                  st.combine(nextSt);
          }
      }
      print(std::cout, st);
  }
  ```
- result is wrong:

  ```
  Next -> 
  Nick 1 90
  Next -> 
  Nick 1 90
  Next -> 
  Nick 1 90
  Next -> 
  Nick 3 360   | Average: 120
  ```
- It should be `Nick 3 270  | Average: 90`
- **I am stuck here.**
- My `print` and `read` functions (and constructor). If number of passed courses > 1, `read` is supposed to get all subsequent marks.

  ```
  std::ostream& print(std::ostream &os, const StudentEntry &st) {
      os << st.getStudentName() << " " << st.passCources << " " << st.markSum
              << "\t | Average: " << st.avgMark() << "\n";
      return os;
  }

  std::istream& read(std::istream &is, StudentEntry &st) {
      std::cout << "Next -> " << std::endl;
      is >> st.name >> st.passCources;
      double mark;
      for (unsigned i = 0; i < st.passCources; ++i) {
          is >> mark;
          st.markSum += mark;
      }
      return is;
  }

  StudentEntry::StudentEntry(std::istream &is) {
      read(is, *this);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each iteration of `while` loop will accumulate `markSum` values in `nextSt` because inside of `read` method it calls

```
st.markSum += mark;
```

you should reset sum before iterating:

```
st.markSum = 0.0;
double mark;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < st.passCources; ++i) {
    is >> mark;
    st.markSum += mark;
}
```